# The machine is stopping working

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Let’s say I am working at a factory in front of a machine and I saw the machine in the process of stopping. Can I say this to a colleague of mine:

- **The machine is stopping working.**

I guess we could say this but I was not completely sure so I’d like to know what you think. I wonder if we can see the act of **“stopping”** as a process and use the structure **“stopping doing something.”**

Comment: You could simply say "The machine is stopping" if the moving parts are slowing down.

Comment: There is a list of verbs that take ing after them. They finished speaking at 10. We starting working at 6. The machine stopped working this morning. start, stop, commence, begin, and a few others. Although The men are stopping working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context described, the suggested sentence is grammatical, but it is not at all idiomatic.

> The machine is stopping

involves no awkward double present participles and fully expresses the meaning because a machine does no work once stopped.